# iterate an array with conditions such that certain elements can be revisited multiple time

Tags: jq

For the input below:

```
{
    "vals": [
      {
        "month": "Jan 2022",
        "value": 0,
        "amount": -200,
        "date": "01-02-2022"
      },
      {
        "month": "Feb 2022",
        "value": 0,
        "amount": -200,
        "date": "28-02-2022"
      }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "date": "01-02-2022",
            "amount": -200
        },
        {
            "date": "04-02-2022",
            "amount": 100
        },
        {
            "date": "28-02-2022",
            "amount": -200
        },
        {
            "date": "10-03-2022"
            "amount": 250
        },
        {
            "date": "12-03-2022"
            "amount": 50
        }
    ]   
}
```

I want the below output

```
{
    "vals": [
      {
        "month": "Jan 2022",
        "value": 37
      },
      {
        "month": "Feb 2022",
        "value": 12
      }
    ]
}
```

for month "Jan 2022" of vals, we have debit amount on 01-02-2022. So need go through the items arrays from 01-02-2022 till the total sum of amount matches with vals "Jan 2022" amount value and we need to the no of days between i.e. 01-02-2022 and 10-03-2022

for month "Feb 2022" instead of going through items array again from first we should continue where we left for Jan 2022.

```
    {
        "date": "10-03-2022"
        "amount": 250
    }
```

of this item 100 is considered for Jan 2022 and 150 is considered for Feb 2022.

so I need to loop items array such that I should continue where I left for an element of vals array.

```
    {
        "date": "10-03-2022"
        "amount": 250
    }
```

this element of items array should be considered twice once for Jan 2022 and second for Feb 2022

But

```
    {
        "date": "04-02-2022"
        "amount": 100
    }
```

should considered only once as the 100 will not completely serve Jan 2022 amount i.e. -200

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem description is not clear, at least to me.  For example, the date of the first .items entry matching the "Jan 2022" amount of -200 is 28-02-2022, so from your description it would seem the count of days for Jan should be the number of days from 01-02-2022 to that date, not the date in March. Please clarify.  Also, since SO is not a free code-writing service, compound questions should normally include more than just a problem specification.  For example, have you solved the subproblem of counting the number of days between two dates?

Comment: you are correct for Jan 2022 no of day should be 37 i.e. from 01-02-2022 to 10-03-2022. No of days I will be able to solve converting the string date to strptime and then mktime. I will get difference between these to days and devide by (24*60*60) to get the no of days.

Comment: Here the main requirement is for each vals array item I need to go through from where I left for previous element of vals array in the items array. I can not use to_entries, range functions as I I need to revisit some of the elements of items array multiple times as explained in the question for {
        "date": "10-03-2022"
        "amount": 250
    }

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are some aspects of the problem which I do not understand, but the following should help as it addresses the key need:

> I need to loop items array such that I should continue where I left for an element of vals array.

The key to doing this cleanly is to define a helper function which allows us to keep track of where to resume the search:

```
# input: [ $index, $array ] where $index is null or >= -1
# output: the first index, $i, in the array for which
#   $i > $index and $array[$i].amount == $v , or else null
def value($v): 
   . as [ $index, $array ]
   | if $index == null then null
     else first( range($index + 1; $array|length) | select($array[.].amount == $v) ) // null
     end ;
```

For computing the number of days between two dates, another helper function will be useful:

```
# Date format: dd-mm-year
def days($finish; $start):
  [$finish, $start]
  | map(strptime("%d-%m-%Y") | mktime) # seconds
  | (.[0] - .[1]) / 86400 + 0.5 | trunc ;
```

Now we have simply to build up the result by visiting the elements of `.vals`:

```
.items as $items
| reduce .vals[] as $val ({ix: 0, date: .vals[0].date, array: []};
    ([.ix, $items] | value($val.amount)) as $ix
    | .ix = $ix
    | if $ix == null
      then .
      else .date as $date
      | .array += [$val | {month, value: days($items[$ix].date; $date) }] 
      | .date = $date
      end )
```

As already stated, this is probably not exactly what you want, but should provide a suitable framework for you.